# How to get headers in httpservice with thrift protocol

Tags: armeria

```java
HelloWorldService.Iface helloService =
        Clients.builder("tbinary+http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello")
               .addHttpHeader("key", "value")
               .build(HelloWorldService.Iface.class);

ServerBuilder sb = Server.builder();
sb.service("/hello", THttpService.of(new HelloServiceImpl()));
sb.http(8080);
Server server = sb.build();
server.start();
```

How do I handle HTTP headers in the server? `THttpService` is a final class, so I can not extend it to handle the headers.

Comment: How to get headers, i think a simple interceptor/filter would do the job, but the question is, how to send headers..!

Answer (score 1):

In your `HelloServiceImpl` class, you can access the current `ServiceRequestContext` using `ServiceRequestContext.current()` to access the request headers and other information:

```java
public class HelloServiceImpl implements HelloWorldService.AsyncIface {
    @Override
    public void hello(...) {
        ServiceRequestContext ctx = ServiceRequestContext.current();
        RequestHeaders headers = ctx.request().headers();
        String value = headers.get("key");
        ...
    }
}
```